# WordPress - redirecting users after login not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in my wordpress custom plugin

```php
<?php

public function role_login_redirect()
{
    $redirect_to;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles) && in_array('vendor', $user->roles) ){
        $redirect_to = site_url('/customers-manage');
        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
        exit;
    } elseif( isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles) && in_array('customer', $user->roles) ){
        $usermeta = get_user_meta( $user->ID );
        if( $usermeta['account_status'][0] === 'pending' || $usermeta['account_status'][0] === 'rejected' ){
            $redirect_to = site_url('/account-error');
            wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
            exit;
        } else {
            $redirect_to = site_url('/user-profile');
            wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
            exit;
        }
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}

add_filter('login_redirect', array($this, 'role_login_redirect'));
```

I'm trying to redirect the users when they login based on the role and on some user meta . I'm facing the issue that the users will be redirected after login to the default wordpress profile dashboard page, this occur with the vendor role and also with customer role. Is there something wrong in the code and how I can prevent users from displaying the default wordpress dashboard correctly??

Since I had a problem with logged in users that will see a blank page if visit the login page, I've tried to add the `template_redirect` filter, but this resulted in the problem I had at the moment.

**UPDATE** I've also noticed that the custom page for the users will be displayed only once. If I do logout and do login form the custom form, the redirect is ignored also if I remove the `wp_safe_redirect` as suggested in a comment.

Comment: `login_redirect` filter is for returning the redirect url, so you can't do `wp_safe_redirect` within this function, you can create a redirect url based on logic and return the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed the `wp_safe_redirect` as suggested in a comment and I've registered the filter with all the arguments. Now seems working correctly. I post the solution for everyone who need the same help

```php
<?php

public function role_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user )
{

    if( isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles) && in_array('vendor', $user->roles) ){
        $redirect_to = site_url('/customers-manage');
    } elseif( isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles) && in_array('customer', $user->roles) ){
        $usermeta = get_user_meta( $user->ID );
        if( $usermeta['account_status'][0] === 'pending' || $usermeta['account_status'][0] === 'rejected' ){
            $redirect_to = site_url('/account-error');
        } else {
            $redirect_to = site_url('/user-profile');
        }
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}

add_filter('login_redirect', array($this, 'role_login_redirect'), 10, 3);
```